# How to get multiple rows and columns using mysql db through django

Tags: python, mysql, django

Getting single row and single column below code is executed sucessfully. How to get multiple columns and rows?

> views.py

```
def get_db_data(request):
    conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost", user = "test_user", passwd = "test_pwd", db = "myproject")
    cursor = conn.cursor ()
    cursor.execute ("SELECT email_address, mobile_number,id, city, state  FROM user")
    if cursor.rowcount == 0:
        html = "<html><body>There is no Faculty member with id %s.</body></html>" % email_address
    else:
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        html = "<html><body>E-Mail address %s.</body></html>" % row[0]
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

UPD:

```
def get_db_data(request):
    conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost", user = "test_user", passwd = "test_pwd", db = "myproject")
    cursor = conn.cursor ()
    cursor.execute ("SELECT email_address, mobile_number,id, city, state  FROM user")
    if cursor.rowcount == 0:
        html = "<html><body>There is no Faculty member with id %s.</body> <html>" % email_address
    else:
        html = "<html>"
        for x in cursor.fetchone():
            html += "<body>E-Mail address %s.</body>" % x
        html += "<html>"
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

All columns

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user")
```

All rows:

```
cursor.fetchall()

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    html = ...
```

and there is one more thing it is not about your problem but you should keep in mind while write `if`

The values `0, None, False` all are false for if statement so it's better to write `if not cursor.rowcount` instead `if cursor.rowcount==0`

Comment: if i do cursor.fetchall() getting only one record. i  want mutiple records and multiple columns how can i do that. Please give me an example.

Comment: Thanks for telling how to call if condition

Comment: You have to iterate over the results

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.

```
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors

def get_db_data(request):
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="test_user", passwd="test_pwd", db="myproject", cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT email_address, mobile_number,id, city, state  FROM user")
    if cursor.rowcount == 0:
        html = "<html><body>There is no Faculty member with id.</body></html>"
    else:
        htm = "<html><body>"
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            html += "Id - {id}, E-Mail address - {email_address}, Mobile Number - {mobile_number}, City - {city}, State {state}. </br>".format(**row)
        html += "</body></html>"
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: Above answer will work, but why you are using SQL Query, you should use Django ORM to fetch data  and should use Django Modal.